# How to return a recordset from a function

Tags: excel, ado, recordset, vba

I'm building a data access layer in Excel VBA and having trouble returning a recordset. The Execute() function in my class is definitely retrieving a row from the database, but doesn't seem to be returning anything.

The following function is contained in a class called DataAccessLayer. The class contains functions Connect and Disconnect which handle opening and closing the connection.

```
Public Function Execute(ByVal sqlQuery As String) As ADODB.recordset
    Dim rs As ADODB.recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.recordset
    Dim recordsAffected As Long

    ' Make sure we're connected to the database.
    If Connect Then
        Set command = New ADODB.command

        With command
            .ActiveConnection = connection
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .CommandType = adCmdText
        End With

        'Set rs = command.Execute(recordsAffected)
        'Set Execute = command.Execute(recordsAffected)
        rs.Open command.Execute(recordsAffected)
        rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
        Set Execute = rs
        Set command = Nothing
        Call Disconnect
    End If
End Function
```

Here's a public function that I'm using in cell A1 of my spreadsheet for testing.

```
Public Function Scott_Test()
    Dim Database As New DataAccessLayer
    'Dim rs As ADODB.recordset
    'Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set rs = New ADODB.recordset

    Set rs = Database.Execute("SELECT item_desc_1 FROM imitmidx_sql WHERE item_no = '11001'")
    'rs.Open Database.Execute("SELECT item_desc_1 FROM imitmidx_sql WHERE item_no = '11001'")
    'rs.Open

    ' This never displays.
    MsgBox rs.EOF

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ' This is displaying #VALUE! in cell A1.
        Scott_Test = rs!item_desc_1
        rs.Close
    End If

    rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was with setting the ActiveConnection = Nothing. The following code works:

```
Public Function Execute(ByVal sqlQuery As String) As ADODB.recordset
    Dim rs As ADODB.recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.recordset
    Dim recordsAffected As Long

    ' Make sure we are connected to the database.
    If Connect Then
        Set command = New ADODB.command

        With command
            .ActiveConnection = connection
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .CommandType = adCmdText
        End With

        rs.Open command.Execute(recordsAffected)

        Set Execute = rs
        Set command = Nothing
        Call Disconnect
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set Execute = recordset
```

creates a pointer to recordset, which you close on exiting the function.
Thats's why it can't contain anything.

I am also relectant on your variable names which are identical to possibe reserved words (recordset). I generally use rs or rsIn or rsWhateverYouWant...

Comment: I moved the close to the calling function, but it still doesn't work. I also changed the variable names to make you feel more comfortable. Above code example has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Patrick, the recordset is a pointer.
The Caller 'Scott_Test' should call recordset.Close instead.

The Execute method CANNOT call recordset.Close, however I believe it is OK to leave the recordset.ActiveConnection = Nothing

Comment: I moved the close to the calling function, but it still doesn't work. Above code example has been updated.