# Create an ADODB connection inside a function VBA-ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to simplify my code, having a module which contains all DB connection functions in one Access, so this is what I've already done:

> Module "DB"

```
Public Function connect() As String
    Dim cn As ADODB.connection    

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=system;Data Source=localhost; User Id= root;Password= root;"
    connect = cn

End Function

Public Function sql(cn As String, query As String) As String

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    cn.Open

    Set rs = cn.Execute(query)

    cn.Close

    sql = rs

End Function
```

> Event when I click in a button

```
Private Sub btn_run_Click()

conexao = connect()
result = sql(conexao, "SELECT TOP 1* FROM  MIS.MP_BASE_ACOES")

End Sub
```

Here is what my Access as an error: 
Translating to en -> "Compilation error: The type defined by the user wasn't defined"

What am I doing wrong? Is that the correct way to define a connection function?

**PS: There's no error in ConnectionString, I just changed some content because it is confidential.**

Edit1: Following FunThomas, I really have forgotten to mark all the references like ActiveX from my project, but it still not working, now with this error:
"Uncompatible argument ByRef"

[image]

Comment: I assume that your compile error comes from a missing reference to `Microsoft Active X DataObjects`, so the type `ADODB.connection` is not known. Anyhow, your code horribly mixes data type `connection` with `string` and will for sure not work

Answer (score 1):

In general, you code has the following errors:

- Wrong usage of functions (Public Function connect() As String)
- The SQL function is not called
- The object `cn` is of type string, and thus it does not have the `Execute` procedure.

Try this and try to assign the `TestMe` to a button. The idea to give the `ConnectionString` as a separate Function is a good one:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ConnectionString() As String

    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=1111111111; Database=ABC; User ID=NotSA; Password=NotTheSaPwd"

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cn  As ADODB.Connection

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    cn.Open (ConnectionString)
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM TABLE", cn

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs!ColumnName
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I assume that I do not work much with functions in VBA so sorry for the wrong usage of the language. Can this code be used in a module? I see that you're using this code to print something, but to turn it more flexible, can it return the array from the query or just to another sql task? like an insert, update?

Comment: @jvbarsou - you can do anything, the printing is just an example.

Comment: how the code would look like turning it more flexible? could you explain?

Comment: @jvbarsou - take a look here for an INSERT INTO example - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834799.aspx

Comment: got it @Vityata, but lets suppose I'm using the TestMe to a insert clause, does not need to return anything, but and if i want to do something different than a while loop? can the TestMe return me the object rs if its set so i can work with it out of the testme scope?

Comment: @jvbarsou - what you need is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463212/how-to-return-a-recordset-from-a-function

Comment: @jvbarsou, you need to learn about functions and about parameter passing ... i think that is what you meant by `module`

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are passing a string when your function requires a connection object. Simply change parameter types accordingly:

```
Public Function sql(cn As ADODB.connection, query As String) As String

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    cn.Open

    Set rs = cn.Execute(query)

    cn.Close

    sql = rs

End Function
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Do I have to change anything else in my code, incuding `connect()` function? Because running it, it returns synthax error:

`Private Sub btn_run_Click()

result = sql(cn as ADODB.Connection,"SELECT TOP 1* FROM  MIS.MP_BASE_ACOES")

End Sub`

Comment: I thought your SQL query had a syntax error but thought you had a typo in above post. Put a space between `TOP 1` and asterisk, `*`.